# How to change name of docker image being built using docker compose build with shell arguments?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Let's say we have this `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  # Base image containing dependencies.
  base:
    image: mycustomimage
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
```

I want to change the name of the image, in this case `mycustomimage`, being built by passing the name to the command line arguments using `--build-arg` with the command `docker compose build`. I tried to run the command:

`docker compose build --build-arg IMAGE_NAME=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE`

with this yaml file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  # Base image containing dependencies.
  base:
    image: ${IMAGE_NAME}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
```

but it didn't replace the name, and instead it defaulted to blank string.

```bash
$ docker compose build --build-arg IMAGE_NAME=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
time="2023-08-28T20:03:44Z" level=warning msg="The \"IMAGE_NAME\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
```

Is there any to do this without modifying the docker-compose.yaml file directly?

Comment: @andreastoga Did my answer solved your doubts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--build-arg` is an option to set built-time variables for services. [Here the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_build/).

In your case, you don't want to pass variables to services but pass a variable to the Docker compose file in order to set the Docker image to use.

To do that you have 3 main options.

*First option*. Create an **.env file** in the same folder of your `docker-compose.yaml` file and put the image name there with

```
echo "IMAGE_NAME=mycustomimage" > .env
```

then, use the variable in your Docker compose file:

```
services:
  base:
    image: "${IMAGE_NAME}"
```

*Second option*. Use an **environment variable from the cli**. Set an environmental variable in your shell with

```
export IMAGE_NAME=mycutomimage
```

and add it to your docker compose file

```
services:
  base:
    environment:
    - IMAGE_NAME
    image: "${IMAGE_NAME}"
```

*Third option*. Use an **environment variable from the docker compose command**. Add the environmental variable in the docker compose file

```
services:
  base:
    environment:
    - IMAGE_NAME
    image: "${IMAGE_NAME}"
```

and start the compose with the variable inside the command

```
IMAGE_NAME=mycustomimage docker-compose up -d
```

Here the [docker compose documentation about how to set enviroment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/) to have a more complete list of choice.